# Restrict installation of app on devices with screen density hdpi or lower

Tags: android, manifest, android-screen-support, hdpi, screen-density

I am developing an android app which is only for devices with high screen densities. i want to restrict my app on devices having 1.5 screen density or lower than that. I searched a lot about this problem and found out that we can handle this by different tags in manifest like

```
 <supports-screens android:smallScreens="false"
    android:normalScreens="false"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
```

I have two devices and both are in normalScreens category. One of them has density equal to 1.5 and other is of 2.0. My question is that how can I restrict my app on devices on the basis of screen densities. 
Using `<compatible-screens>` tag should not be the solution of this as google documentation says, "Any size and density combination not explicitly declared in this tag will be restricted from installing the app".

What to do guys please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

> Any size and density combination not explicitly declared in this tag will be restricted from installing the app.

It sounds like `<compatible-screens>` *is* what you want. You'll have to list every possible combination of screens you *do* support. That's everything except `ldpi`, `mdpi`, and `hdpi`.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element
https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution#FilteringHandsetApps

So this is a good start:

```
<compatible-screens>
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi"/>
</compatible-screens>
```

The documentation lists more supported values for screen density:

- 320 (xhdpi)
- 360
- 420
- 480 (xxhdpi)
- 560
- 640 (xxxhdpi)

The problem is if there's a device with different value that you *don't* include in your manifest it won't see your app in the Store. For example Sony Xperia Z5 Premium has a density of [~800 dpi](https://pixensity.com/list/phone/) and it won't get you app unless you specify screen density of `800` in your manifest.

```
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="800"/>
```

*That's just my guess.*

So before you go this route, ask yourself, if you really need this. If instead it would be acceptable to inform the user when they first run the app that visual fidelity may not be as high as intended due to atypical display density (or what not, I don't really know your use case). Let the user decide.

Comment: Actually i dont want to use this tag because google states in its documentation that, `Normally, you should not use this manifest element. Using this element can dramatically reduce the potential user base for your application, by not allowing users to install your application if they have a device with a screen configuration that you have not listed`. May be there is some other way to do this. Thanks

Comment: Let me put it this way: Blocking all devices with certain screen densities tends to have the side effect of "reducing potential user base" exactly by the amount of users using devices with those blocked screen densities. Your case definitely falls in this abnormal category. There is no other way because typically you want an app to run on any device. Your app is special in this regard. Makes sense?

Comment: If you don't want to lose the users which won't be able to run your app because of their low density screens, your only other option is to buy all of them new phones.

Comment: Although the advice is correct that you have to specify all available values for the screen density if not a potential device will be left out, I can't find any device example that uses screen density 800 yet. I just checked the device catalog in Google Play Console and Sony Xperia Z5 Premium has a density of 480 for some reason.